# the display of the SVG drawing via javascript does not display

Tags: javascript, html, svg

My SVG table made in javascript is not displayed while if we look at the HTML source code created by javascript in the console, the SVG HTML elements are present and if I copy and paste this code into the HTML page, the table is displayed correctly. I don't understand what is preventing display directly with javascript. Thank you for your help . Below is the HTML and JS code

**Code HTML :**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test SVG</title>
    <style>
      div, svg {width:800px; height:100px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div0"></div>
    <script src="tablature.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Code Javascript : tablature.js**

```
var nomDiv = div0;
var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

function creTablature(x,y,W) {
    var rect = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'rect');
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', x);
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', y);
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', '100');
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', W);
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'none');
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', '#000');
    nomSVG.appendChild(rect);
    var ligne = document.createElementNS(svgns, "line");
    ligne.setAttributeNS(null, "x1", x);
    ligne.setAttributeNS(null, "y1", y + 33);
    ligne.setAttributeNS(null, "x2", x + W);
    ligne.setAttributeNS(null, "y2", y + 33);
    ligne.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', '#000');
    nomSVG.appendChild(ligne);
    var ligne = document.createElementNS(svgns, "line");
    ligne.setAttributeNS(null, "x1", x);
    ligne.setAttributeNS(null, "y1", y + 66);
    ligne.setAttributeNS(null, "x2", x + W);
    ligne.setAttributeNS(null, "y2", y + 66);
    ligne.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', '#000');
    nomSVG.appendChild(ligne); 
    creBar(0,0,40);   
}
function creBar(x,y,L) {
    var ligne = document.createElementNS(svgns, "line");
    ligne.setAttributeNS(null, "x1", x + L);
    ligne.setAttributeNS(null, "y1", y);
    ligne.setAttributeNS(null, "x2", x + L);
    ligne.setAttributeNS(null, "y2", y + 100);
    ligne.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', '#000');
    nomSVG.appendChild(ligne);
}
function addText(x,y,texte) {
    var newText = document.createElementNS(svgns,"text");
    newText.setAttributeNS(null,"x",x);      
    newText.setAttributeNS(null,"y",y);   
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(texte);
    newText.appendChild(textNode);
    dnomSVG.appendChild(newText);
}

function insertTablature(svgID) {
    let svg = document.createElement("svg");
    svg.id = svgID;
    nomDiv.appendChild(svg);
    nomSVG = document.getElementById(svgID); 
    creTablature(0,0,800);
    addText(14,54,"P");
    addText(14,88,"T");
  }

  insertTablature("svg1");
```

Comment: document.createElement("svg"); is wrong, it needs to be createElementNS as you use elsewhere.

Comment: Use createElementNS when you create the svg element. Also you may consider adding a viewBox attribute to the svg element or at least a width and height

Comment: The bug actually comes from there, it works much better with the right instruction :)
thanks to you two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a modern browsers (anything above IE11) you can create your own HTML tag `<svg-tablature>`

And use HTML:

```
<svg-tablature width="200" fill="red"></svg-tablature>

<svg-tablature width="300" fill="pink"></svg-tablature>
```

To create:

[image]

With a **one time** (per pageload) **Custom Element** definition:

*Disclaimer: this is example code; it needs more tweaking to fit your code example*

```html
<style>  svg-tablature { display:inline-block; width:200px; } </style>
<svg-tablature width="200" fill="red"></svg-tablature>
<svg-tablature width="300" fill="pink"></svg-tablature>
<script>
  customElements.define('svg-tablature', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      let x = this.getAttribute("x") || 0;
      let y = this.getAttribute("y") || 0;
      let width= this.getAttribute("width") || 100;
      let height= this.getAttribute("height") || 100;
      let fill = this.getAttribute("fill") || "green";
      let stroke = "black";
      this.svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","svg");
      this.svg.setAttribute("viewBox",`0 0 ${width} ${height}`);
      this.append(this.svg);
      this.add("rect",{x:0,y:0,height,width,fill,stroke});
      stroke="blue";
      this.add("line",{x1:x,y1:"33%",x2:"100%",y2:"33%",stroke});
      this.add("line",{x1:x,y1:"66%",x2:"100%",y2:"66%",stroke});
      let L = 40;
      this.add("line",{x1:x+L,y1:y,x2:x+L,y2:"100%",stroke});
      this.addtext(14,54,"P");
      this.addtext(14,88,"T");
    }
    add(type, attrs){
      let element= document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",type);
      Object.keys(attrs).forEach(name => element.setAttribute(name,attrs[name]));
      return this.svg.appendChild(element);
    }
    addtext(x,y,txt){
      this.add("text",{x,y}).innerHTML =txt;
    }
  });
</script>
```

**Notes:**

- `add`  and  `addtext` are **methods** on the `<svg-tablature>` DOM Element

  So you can always call:

  `document.getElementById( someID ).addtext( 20 , 30 , "Hello World!")`

Comment: This code is very clean and works great. Currently I do not have a good enough command of javascript to adapt it in my program. I will study it quietly to progress.
thank you very much

Comment: Take it line by line, read the line, try to explain what it does, make a small change, see what happens... success